# Questions about ratio and overlapping figures

Tags: geometry, ratio, rectangles

As I am helping my younger brother on his math papers (bought on external sources), I came across a question that seems unsolvable.

I feel that the question is not complete as they did not state the overlapped area of A and B. And the answer is supposed to be 5/9 from the answer sheet with no workings.

[Picture of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMO2N.jpg)

**Question:**

> The ratio of the area of Rectangle A to the area of Rectangle B to the area of Rectangle C is 1:2:3. If one-third of Rectangle B is shaded, what total fraction of the whole figure is not shaded if all three rectangles overlap?

[image: Diagram of the 3 rectangles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested in your notes, you can assume that the areas $A$, $B$ and $C$ are respectively $3$, $6$ and $9$. The text indicates that "one-third" of $B$ is shaded (I assume by $A$). Hence only $\frac 23 \times 6 = 4$ is the visible area of $B$. Since $B$ fully overlaps $C$, only $9-6 = 3$ is the visible area of $C$. Hence, the total unshaded area is $3 + 4 + 3 = 10$ and the total area is $3+6+9=18$. Hence, the unshaded ratio is indeed $\frac 5 9$ as claimed in the answers sheet.

*Compared with your reasoning, I guess the key part is that although the text does not explicitly give the overlap area of $A$ and $B$, they DO say that one-third of $B$ is shaded, which is sufficient information to conclude.*

Comment: Thanks for answering, this seems like one way to get the provided answer. Granted it did not specify it to be drawn to scale, but having that shaded part to be one-third of B seems far-fetched. I guess the publisher lack some illustrators ‍♂️

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, it is quite common that the pictures of geometry exercises are not to scale (or even purposefully to a wrong scale) to avoid "hacking your way" to the solution by measuring anything.